# Making sense of symbol table entry (when header function is not present)

Tags: android, c++, gcc, linker, java-native-interface

I have a JNI function in a C++ library.

When I create the library using cmake (but forget to put function declaration) in the header file, the library is created successfully.

When I look for function name in library symbol table I get following output

```
nm libuserlibrary.so | grep printxx
00506e60 T _Z60Java_com_example_user_myapplication_userlibrary_printxxP7JNIEnv_P8_jobject
```

But when I give function declaration in the header file, I get following output

```
nm libuserlibrary.so | grep printxx
00506e50 T Java_com_example_user_myapplication_userlibrary_printxx
```

**Why is there this difference between these two symbol table entries? What is the purpose of `_Z60` and `P7JNIEnv_P8_jobject` around the function name?**

I also noticed that in the first case, I cannot call the JNI funciton from Android java code (it says unsatisfied-linker-error, implementation not found).

Comment: You use the same command twice and get different output?

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes. only difference is in second case i declare function in headerfile.

Comment: Sounds like perhaps when you put it in the header file, it treats it as if it was `extern "C"`? The first function signature looks like it has C++ name mangling; the second looks like it does not.

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows function overloads and namespaces like Java does. So, it annotated the function name with parameter information so the linker can bind to the correct overload.

JNI was designed for C which does not allow function overloads or namespaces.  So  it invented it's own annotation system and provides the javah tool to help you use it. The header can be used in C++ too. C++ was designed to allow some functions to be called as if they written in C. The header has code that indicates that to the compiler. So, put it all together and you can write Java-callable functions in C++.